# Not able to move files from Google Drive to Blobstore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api, blobstore

I was moving files from Google drive to blobstore using the below code . But now the   FileWriteChannel is deprecated and the code is not working. Is there an alternative solution for this problem ?

```
    private BlobKey getBlobKey(File f, DriveObject driveObject)
        throws IOException, MalformedURLException { 

    Drive service = ((GoogleDrive) driveObject).getService();

    byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) f.getFileSize().intValue()];
    GenericUrl url = new GenericUrl(f.getDownloadUrl());
    HttpResponse response = service.getRequestFactory()
                .buildGetRequest(url).execute();

    InputStream is = response.getContent();

    FileService fileService = FileServiceFactory.getFileService();
    AppEngineFile file = null;
    boolean lock = true;
    try {
        file = fileService.createNewBlobFile("application/zip");
        FileWriteChannel writeChannel = fileService.openWriteChannel(
                    file, lock);

        int len;
        while ((len = is.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer, 0, len);
        writeChannel.write(bb);
        }
        writeChannel.closeFinally();

    } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

        BlobKey bk = fileService.getBlobKey(file);

    return bk;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Java Client library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/getstarted):

```
GcsOutputChannel outputChannel =
    gcsService.createOrReplace(fileName, GcsFileOptions.getDefaultInstance());
outputChannel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(content));
outputChannel.close();
```

Comment: If you plan to load the complete content into memory (hopefully small files) then you can use the createOrReplace method that accepts the content (as it will save you RPC calls). Also, you should consider using [gcloud-java-storage](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-java/tree/master/gcloud-java-storage) which works in AE as well as outside of AE.

Comment: But i need to store the files in Blobstore instead of google buckets. I am migrating ten thousand files from Google Drive to blobstore .

Comment: Blobstore is listed in the documentation as "superseded storage solution". It means it can be discontinued/deprecated at some point.